# How to get dump file of CodeIgniter application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dump

I have some questions regarding dumps in PHP CodeIgniter framework:

What are all steps to enable error logging? 
 How to create system dump? 
Must it be done manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CodeIgniter has some error logging functions built in.**

To enable logging Do this way

1.Make your /application/logs folder is writable if not make it

2.In /application/config/config.php set

```
 $config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

3.Now to log errors  Use something like this:

```
 if ($some_var == '')
 {
    log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
 }
 else
 {
    log_message('debug', 'Some variable was correctly set');
 }
 log_message('info', 'The purpose of some variable is to provide some value.');
```

4. Go to the logs folder there will be a file showing your errors

For mor info :

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html